# Object Constructors

Tags: javascript, loops, object, constructor

I have a problem with creating a new Object in the constructor
My Aim is to take the user input and from that create a new object and push into an array using the constructor.
The problem is that when I try to fill the new input to create a new object it just replaced the old one with undefined values.
MY code :

```
let Book = document.querySelector("#one");
let Author = document.querySelector("#two");
let Year = document.querySelector("#three");
let Btn = document.querySelector("button");

Btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  Book = Book.value;
  Author = Author.value;
  Year = Year.value;

  let myLibrary = [];
  function newBook(name, author, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
  }
  function addBookToLibrary(book, author, year) {
    const Books = new newBook(book, author, year);
    myLibrary.push(Books);
  }
  addBookToLibrary(Book, Author, Year);
  console.log(myLibrary);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let Book = document.querySelector("#one");
let Author = document.querySelector("#two");
let Year = document.querySelector("#three");
let Btn = document.querySelector("button");

let myLibrary = [];

Btn.addEventListener("click", () => {


  function newBook(name, author, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
  }
  function addBookToLibrary(book, author, year) {
    const Books = new newBook(book, author, year);
    myLibrary.push(Books);
  }
  addBookToLibrary(Book.value, Author.value, Year.value);
  console.log(myLibrary);
});
```

There are two mistakes in above code:

1. You are using local state of `let myLibrary = [];` which will be created on every click. It should be moved to a higher level so that on every click the value added can be preserved.
2. You are using same name of variables inside your function, which are overriding the Dom reference.